# Half bidirectional transmission shaft gear box solve

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, automotive-engineering, gears

I'm wondering how to accomplish some kind of gear box that would reverse only the direction of one side of the two shafts on it, like in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting challenge! I'm not sure that such a mechanism actually exists. Also, I'm not sure if this is a purely mechanical device (perhaps it should have controlled electronic components). But I would take the following as one of the possible options:

[image]

**Mode 1:** in this mode, the main transmission shaft is connected to the subsequent ones through a pair of CVT or bevel gears. When the main shaft rotates counterclockwise (or clockwise), the two following shafts rotate in opposite directions.

**Mode 2:** A hypothetical "spring-loaded" shaft with an auxiliary CVT or bevel gear hidden within the body of the main transmission shaft. The second CVT or bevel gear is "pressed" to the body of one of the subsequent shafts. And in the body of another auxiliary shaft, another shaft is hidden. In mode two, the auxiliary CVT or bevel gears must be connected, as well as two auxiliary shafts. In this mode, the main shaft transfers rotation to the "augmented" subsequent shafts and they begin to rotate in the same direction.

There are, of course, many questions about such a design. But I decided to do this exercise. Perhaps my answer will be useful to you. I also do not rule out that there is a much simpler gearbox!

Answer (score 1):

You just gave me a great idea, i think.
Check it out.

[image]

Whats inside the dotted line 1 moves together with the main shaft, in a way that when the shaft goes down the bevels in 1 are connected to the side shafts making them move together in the same direction and when the shaft goes up bevel 2 connects to the side shafts making them rotate in opposite directions, this will gave me the effect i wanted.

Comment: Yes, I understand the construction that you brought here. I am very glad if I could help you, and you have learned some important starting points for your work.